# assetBundle Returns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am downloading assetBundle from server using UnityWebRequest and it is working good in unity editor but in andriod it gives null value can  someone help

```
public IEnumerator DownloadAsset(string url, string assetName)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            AGUIMisc.ShowToast("Not Null");
            GameObject temp = bundle.LoadAsset(assetName) as GameObject;
            var newobjj = Instantiate(temp);
            newobjj.transform.parent = maleparent.transform;
        }
        else
        {
            AGUIMisc.ShowToast("Null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging www.error to see if any errors occured while downloading?

Comment: No let me check and i will let you know

Comment: no error in www.error

Answer (score 0):

### Target-platform Android:

The AssetBundles need to be built in the target-platform where they are going to be used at later.
Since you want to use the AssetBundles in Android, the *target-platform* should also be **Android when you build your AssetBundles**.

Please also check:

You should set [UnityWebRequest.downloadHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-downloadHandler.html) first before call [UnityWebRequest.SendWebRequest()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SendWebRequest.html) to use [DownloadHandlerAssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.html).

```
    public System.Collections.IEnumerator DownloadAsset(string url, string assetName)
    {
        using (var uwr = new UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest(url, UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET))
        {
            uwr.downloadHandler = new UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerAssetBundle(url, 0);
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
            AssetBundle bundle = UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(uwr);
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                AGUIMisc.ShowToast("Not Null");
                GameObject temp = bundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>(assetName);
                var newobj = GameObject.Instantiate(temp);
                newobj.transform.parent = maleparent.transform;
            }
            else
            {
                AGUIMisc.ShowToast("Null");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will let you know after check

Comment: same problem ! it runs fine in unity editor but in  andriod, bundle value is null @Beautyfull Castle

Comment: Did you build asset bundles target platform for Android? [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles.html)